# Start the wrong activity in Android project

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have 2 app and they will communicate with each other with 3rd push notification SDK.

Step1:
in APP1
activity A(MAIN and launcher)->start activity B(this.finish() in A)->Press Home Button

Step2:
in APP2
send msg to APP1 with SDK

Step3():
in APP1:
activity A start in APP1
and
msg was received in receiver of APP1.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityA"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

My question: Why Activity A was Launched?

But ActivityA was not started When I send msg to APP1 with the test web page of SDK.

Comment: This is way far from being clear, are you asking why activity A was launched or A was not started. anyhow, if the question is why Activity A wasnt launched when your APP1 receiver got the message, then this manifest snippet has nothing to do with it, as you should start an INTENT activity in the receiver code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of your notification. As an example, this is a behaviour similar to the one in the WhatsApp app: since having the WhatsApp app continuously polling their servers for new messages is unfeasible, what they do is having their servers sending notifications to the corresponding devices when there is a new message, **waking up the app in the device** so it can ask the server for the new messages.

EDIT: Your code on how you send the notification from APP2 and how you receive it in APP1 would help (you're probably doing it wrong on both sides I think).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Finally, I found that the 3rd push notification SDK start the wrong activity.